# Unable to use reverse search when I first open SSH shell

Tags: ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

When I SSH into a server that has ZSH setup, I initially can't use `CTRL + R` to reverse search.

I verified the shell is ZSH via:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
```

However, when I run the zsh executable again:

```
$ /usr/bin/zsh
```

`CTRL + R` begins to work as expected. I don't have this issue in my local terminal. Any ideas how to get `CTRL + R` to work when I first SSH in without needing to call `/usr/bin/zsh`?

Edit: it looks like using an interactive shell when SSH'ing in works. Ex: `ssh -t host 'exec /usr/bin/zsh'` works but `ssh -t host 'exec /usr/bin/zsh -l'` doesn't.

Comment: By its nature, using key combinations (Ctrl-R, Ctrl-A,....) makes sense only in an interactive shell, because in a non-interactive shell, you don't expect any interaction using a keyboard.